# Beamer: set position of custom image in title frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, positioning

I want to add a custom image to my title frame in beamer. To do that, I use :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\author{usernumber}
\title{title}
\logo{logo} 
\institute{institute}
\date{date}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=.5\textheight]{image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output I am getting]

This results in the image appearing under the date. Is it possible to have the image next to the author, institute and date instead ? What is the easiest way to move the image?

[image: Something more like the result I'm trying to get]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\defbeamertemplate*{title page}` to define your own custom title frame template. To do so, I copied the title page template from `beamerinnerthemedefault.sty` (which you loaded through `\usetheme{default}`)  and added the minipage environments in order to make sure the titleimages is shown side by side with author, institution and date. (Added lines are highlighted using `%<------`in the following MWE)

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mycustomtitlepage}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth} %<------
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
    \end{minipage}% %<------
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}%<------
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \end{minipage}%<------
  \endgroup
  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\author{usernumber}
\title{title}
\logo{logo} 
\institute{institute}
\date{date}

\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```